# Vim permanent syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using `:set syntax=javascript` whenever I work on TypeScript files for example. I want to set the syntax automatically based on my file type. Now here's the thing, I've done it before by adding:
`au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufReadPost *.ts set syntax=javascript`
to my `~/.vimrc` file, however, it doesn't seem to be working anymore.

Here is the contents of my `.vimrc` file. Is there a reason why this wouldn't work?

```
colorscheme atom-dark-256
set number
set autoindent
set guifont=monaco:h12
set expandtab
set tabstop=4 shiftwidth=4 expandtab

au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufReadPost *.ts set syntax=javascript
au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufReadPost *.handlebars set syntax=HTML
au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufReadPost *.twig set syntax=HTML
au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufReadPost *.theme set syntax=PHP
```

I'm sure it used to work just fine, but it just stopped for some reason. Any ideas? I'm using MacVim if that helps?

Comment: Have you tried `au BufNewFile,BufRead,BufReadPost *.ts set filetype=javascript`

Comment: What does `it just stopped` mean? Does TypeScript files have no syntax or other syntax? (`set syntax?`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us set the filetype of `*.ts` as javascript so that it applies `javascript` syntax using

```
au BufEnter,BufRead *.ts set filetype=javascript
```

Comment: Setting the filetype instead of syntax worked! Thank you very much :)